# Angular, SignalR, WebAPI beginning questions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I do not know if a good idea to group all these together, and let me know if I should take this post down if it is doing something incorrect or silly. But I just gradated college and am going in for an entry level job and I am about to take technical assessment that deals with some extra stuff than I am not familiar with: Angular, SignalR, and WebAPI.

As an entry level candidate: What are some questions I should be prepared to be asked and answer?

I can find more on interview questions Angular than the other two, but any sites or knowledge of questions would really be appreciated.

Right now I am trying to get the basic understanding of each by watching a tutorial over each, but I know that is going to be a lot of information of a broad area of each, so I am trying to understand what parts I really need to concentrate my scope of focus.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this should be moved over to [The Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: For SignalR and WebApi you can try www.asp.net/signalr and www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you very much. Sorry for taking so long to give it the check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking to ramp up on Angular I would suggest [Egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons). They have an amazing catalog of angular videos.

For your .NET related topics (SignalR & Web API), I'd heavily recommend Pluralsight.net.

**Angular key Points**:

- **Two way data binding**. How does it work in Angular versus other
  libraries/frameworks?
- **Controllers**. What is the proper usage? Usually only the middle man that carries the data from the server to the view.
- **Directives**. Reusable components. Be able to write one.
- **Scope**. What components use scope? How do you share it across your application?
- **Testing**. Be able to write unit tests for Angular.

I'd recommend watching some of those resources and building a sample application to help cement everything you will learn.

**Web API key points:**

- **HTTP Based Web Service**. This however, does not always mean RESTFUL.
- **RPC vs. REST**. Know the difference between the ideologies and be able to explain them.
- **Security**. How do you secure an API?
- **Fiddler**. A tool you can use to test your API (among other things).

I would create a sample API and use Fiddler to hit the endpoints. Have this API be able to do the basic CRUD actions for one type of resource/entity.

**SignalR key points:**

- **Websockets**. Know what a websocket it. Why is it useful? How is it different than a regular connection?
- **Server / Browser support**. Know which browsers and servers support web sockets.
- **Fallback**. When websockets aren't available, what does SignalR do?
- **Hubs**. What is the significance of a SignalR hub?

**Wrapping it all up.**

I would recommend creating an individual sample project for each one of these practices. Once you feel comfortable with all of them I would create a project that encompasses all three.

Comment: About Web API, it can definitely be used to create RESTful web services.

Comment: @elolos Of course it can be. However, some think that just by creating an API Controller you have a RESTful service. My point was that not all HTTP based services are RESTful.